# Goldbach-like and Collatz-like conjectures and theorems

Tags: arithmetic, big-list, conjectures, natural-numbers

I am looking for examples of conjectures and famously hard-to-prove theorems which can be stated in the form:

> For each natural number $n$, $P(n)$.

where $P$ is a predicate of natural numbers that is either (1) known to be decidable, or at least (2) known to be semi-decidable, and can be more or less easily shown to be true for many small natural numbers (and can be shown to be true for all numbers for which it is true).

Conjectures and theorems of the form

> There are infinitely many natural numbers $n$ such that $P(n)$.

also fit the case (2) if the property $P$ is decidable or semi-decidable.

Examples for the case (1) with decidable $P$ are preferable, because in such case the conjecture can be easily disproved by a counterexample. It is also preferable that the conjecture could be easily explained to non-specialists.

So, [Fermat's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem) does not fit, but [Goldbach's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture) and [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) do.

> *Goldbach's conjecture*. Every even integer greater than 2 can be written as the sum of two primes.

> *Collatz conjecture*. Start from any natural number. If the number is even, divide it by $2$. If it is odd, multiply it by $3$ and add $1$. Repeat. After repeating enough times, the number $1$ will appear in the sequence.

I think that examples of that kind can be useful when discussing mathematics with people who believe that to prove something it is enough to test sufficiently many times.

Comment: You can refer to the unsolved million dollar millennium problems.

Comment: There are many posts collecting a huge number of such open conjectures, see for example [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/100265/not-especially-famous-long-open-problems-which-anyone-can-understand). It is quite some task to test if they acceptable for you (fit, as you say), which I would like to leave to you. But is it is fun to read these conjectures.

Comment: Examples where testing failed to find a fundamental flaw in a engineering applications may perhaps be of interest. E.g., the [Ariane 5 explosion](https://www.esa.int/Newsroom/Press_Releases/Ariane_501_-_Presentation_of_Inquiry_Board_report).

Comment: To convince people that testing a large number of times isn't a proof, you could also cite conjectures that are false but which only have large counterexamples. There are several posts on this subject on SE, for example https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15444/examples-of-eventual-counterexamples.

Comment: @ArthurVause, yes, this is what i am looking for in particular.

Comment: You can put a lot of problems in these forms. Basic Goldbach  restatement : every natural number greater than $3$, is equidistant at least $2$ primes. Legendre necessary condition : for all natural numbers $m$, there exists a prime between $m$ and $m+4\lfloor\sqrt{m}\rfloor+4$  . What's the big deal ...

Comment: Fermat's last theorem is not difficult to understand. The meaning of the statement can easily be explained to a layman and Collatz is not semidecidable. There is no clearcut way to rule out a divergent trajectory. So, it might be possible that there is a counterexample that we cannot prove to be a counterexample (in the case of Goldbach this is impossible)

Comment: @Peter, Collatz conjecture is semi-decidable in the sense that the set of initial values for which it it true is evidently semi-decidable. For Fermat's last theorem, it is not evident that the set of $n$'s for which it holds is semi-decidable. (But the set of $n$'s for which it fails is evidently semi-decidable.)

Comment: @Alexey In this sense , of course.